# Android Resources doesn't display at runtime

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bitmap, android-drawable

I have few images that i want to use for the help. Where each image will be used in one activity. i have the images in drawable directory and referencing them using aliases for the different configurations. the images are extension is png.

in the UI designer the image is displayed, but not in run-time. it show white view

my Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/help_img_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/todays_reminders_help"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/help_chx_dont_show"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dont_show_help" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my drawable todays_reminders_help.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:src="@drawable/todays_reminders_activity_help" >

</bitmap>
```

[image: at the designer]

[image: at run-time]

i am getting white view at run-time not the image i am referencing? this happen on my test device.

However, when i test on the emulator it worked with no issue

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and/or restarting Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

You can try couple of things:
1. In your `todays_reminders_help.xml`, try to set the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`
2. Just to make sure if things are working as expected, you can test by setting a non-zero height for View with id `help_img_screen`. i.e replace

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/help_img_screen"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
 ..../>
```

with

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/help_img_screen"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
 ..../>
```

and see if that helps. If it works, then you need to figure out why layout_weight is not working - you might have to use hierarchy viewer tool to see why it's not working.

Lastly, i would recommend that you approach this problem in a different way -
Make the `View` an `ImageView` and in real time i.e in the Java code, you can set the image src or background dynamically based on the activity/context. You can completely avoid using another layout file `todays_reminders_help.xml`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Funny part is that it works, even with my old code in the emulator, but not my galaxy nexus.

Comment: Does your code work only on emulators and strictly not working on ANY device? Or is it running on emulators and certain devices (phones and/or tablets)? Send me your project and i will see what could be the issue. Thx.

Comment: i have tried it on one more device, Note 2, it worked. it is only my test device, Galaxy Nexus, where it is not working now. i will test it in more devices